# PowerBI Automated Report Mailings

Tags: python-3.x, powerbi, power-automate

I have a Power BI dataset which contains a list of actions for project owners to do, one of the tables has "Final Contact".  I want to e-mail each "Final Contact" a predefined template HTML and attach an Excel .xlsx containing a list of things they need to do.

Any ideas of the best way to do this?  These were the options I was considering:

1. Create a Python Script to run in Azure and use the Power BI API to pull the data and get Python to send the email
2. Power automate? I looked at Power automate but it didn't really seem to do what I needed, unless I missed something
3. Can Power BI create an automated extract somewhere making it easier for option 1?
4. Get each owner to filter the Power BI and subscribe but this is hit and miss and annoyingly Power BI sends the data as an image
5. Using Excel macros and connecting to the data set.  This is a maybe but it requires manual intervention